# Using a WPF application to plot 2 line graphs and get their intesection points

Tags: c#, wpf, graph, charts

I need to plot a 2D continuous line graph using a WPF application and find the intersection points on the graph given a particular Y-axis value. I have plotted the graph using the Chart control in WPF (Microsoft Visual Studio 2015) but I'm unable to determine the intersection points on the graph. Please point me in the right direction.
Also, is it possible to determine the crests and troughs on the graph after finding the intersection points?

Comment: Paste the code - what you've already done.

Comment: You won't need a chart tool (or not even WPF) to find these points in your data. This is plain math.

Comment: The line graph is not plotted as per an equation. They are values recorded over a period of time.